# Mono framework on Visual Studio 2019 - target/compile/debug

Tags: c#, .net, mono, visual-studio-2019

Before any question, I did a lot of research on Google and S.O. , and I found only old and obsolete threads without any help for my problem.

so...

*1. First question:*

I wonder if it's possible to target the installed Mono framework directly from Visual Studio 2019. 
I know that at the time of writing, Mono 6.4.0.198 is released and it supports almost all features of .NET 4.7 (and C# 7.0), so I created a simple project targeting FW4.7.2 and it works fine so far.

I just wanted to know if I can create a project entirely on Mono Framework with no other reference than Mono assemblies.

I did a lot of research and the only thing I found is this: https://erictummers.com/2012/01/25/target-mono-from-visual-studio/
but i'd rather not mess with the registry and assemblies files.

*2. Second question:*

I would like to build and debug my Mono code directly on the target machine (Raspberry Pi). It's possible to do so in Visual Studio 2019? 
I managed to compile a C++ program directly on the RasPi, so i thought it might be possible to do the same for Mono/C#.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: When the future is clearly .NET Core (.NET 5), it is just a waste of time to use Mono, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Comment: I'm definitely switching to .NET Core. I've just installer .NET Core 3.0 on a RaspberryPi and succesfully ran a simple console app.

Comment: @LexLi That's only the case if you don't need a dependency that isn't yet .NET Core or .NET Standard compliant

Comment: @blenderfreaky a dependency that is not compliant to .NET Core or .NET Standard has almost zero possibility to be compliant to Mono, so there is little room for discussion.

Comment: @LexLi Emgu.CV is explicitly Mono-compatible, yet they still don't support .NET Core

Comment: Also, due to the ARM6 processor, .NET Core won't run on a Raspberry Pi Zero, so Mono is your only choice